# How does the Date.getDate() function work?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm planning to write a couple of date util functions for my project, but cannot understand why `Date.prototype.getDate` is returning weird numbers. For example:

I ran the following code:

```
alert(new Date(2019, 04, 00).getDate());
```

In my head I was expecting to receive 31 (the number of days of May), but received 30!

The same happened with the following snippet:

```
alert(new Date('2019-04-01').getDate());
```

In this case, I was expecting to receive 1 because according to the documentation I found in MDN:

> The getDate() method returns the day of the month for the specified date according to local time.

But instead received 31!

And finally, when ran:

```
alert(new Date('2019-04-02').getDate());
```

I was expecting to see 2, but saw 1! (which has nothing to do with the previous logic!)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `new Date("2019-04-01")` is parsed as the April 1st while `new Date(2019, 04, 00)` is May 0th aka. *May 1st - 1day* or *last day of April*. And while this particular string is parsed as an UTC timecode (in my dev-tools), the numbers are parsed as local timezone. That's also the source of this confusion: `was expecting to see 2, but saw 1!`. *"What am I doing wrong?"* You're seem to be a complete newbie at DateTimes. Warning, I have not found any implementation/language where they didn't give me headaches at some point. Check out [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @Thomas—"2019-04-01" is parsed as UTC, but *getDate* uses the local timezone and might return 30 March or 1 April depending on the host timezone setting.

Answer (score 1):

The Date methods "fix" weird non-real dates. If you set the date (day-of-month) to zero, you get the last day of the previous month. All of the setter methods behave similarly.

Note also that months are numbered from zero: January is 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, you're getting `30` because you're checking the number of days in the 4th month - April. May is the 5th month. Here's a demo - with February as the 2nd month as well:

```js
console.log(new Date(2019, 04, 00).getDate());
console.log(new Date(2019, 05, 00).getDate());
console.log(new Date(2019, 02, 00).getDate());
```

The second case does actually produce `1`:

```js
console.log(new Date('2019-04-01').getDate());
```

And the third case does actually produce `2`:

```js
console.log(new Date('2019-04-02').getDate());
```

Comment: Aren't months zero indexed? `04` should be May not `April`.

Comment: I see, but that's a bit weird because I read in MDN that months are 0-basis:
`Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.`

Comment: That's weird I agree - but even removing the leading zeroes from the first example still makes `2` February.

Comment: It's funny because I'm still seeing the numbers I put in the question... I think my issue is the timezone. Here the timezone offset is -03:00

Comment: `2` is March not February. `new Date(2019, 02,01)` is March 1. `new Date(2019, 02,00)` goes backward — so it's the end of Feb. `new Date(2019, 02,-58)` is new years day.

Comment: Aha! Well that clarifies the matter a bit. What about the other cases @MarkMeyer?

Comment: The other case is different because `new Date('2019-04-01')` and `new Date(2019, 04, 01)` return dates for different zones. It's all much easier if you forget `getDate()` for second and just look at what `new Date()` is returning. This is probably one of the reason people discourage passing a string to `new Date()`

Comment: I understand. If you create an answer I'll be happy to mark it as the right answer. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
new Date(2019, 04, 00)
```

will produce a date for the zeroth day of May, 2019 which is interpreted as the last day of April, which is the 30th, so:

```
new Date(2019, 04, 00).getDate()
```

returns 30.

In:

```
new Date('2019-04-01')
```

the string is (illogically) parsed as UTC. The *getDate* method uses the host timezone setting to determine the local date, so:

```
new Date('2019-04-01').getDate()
```

might return 1 (April) or 31 (March) depending on whether the host timezone offset is positive or negative respectively.

E.g. for a user at UTC +0530 the local date will be 2019-04-01 05:30:00, but for a user at UTC -0400 the local date will be 2019-03-31 20:00:00.